# Как проигрывают пари

Tags: выбор-слов, переводы

*Выиграть* можно *с перевесом* или *с преимуществом*.
А с чем можно *проиграть*?

Контекст:
Я перевожу сайт, в котором пользователи могут предлагать друг другу пари, в оригинале challenge.  И нужно про все это писать сообщения.
Например,

> Пользователь Вася Пупкин предлагает пользователю Таня Галина пари на 5 игроденег в игру Стреляй на меткость.

Затем

> Пользователь Таня Галина выиграла пари у пользователя Вася Пупкин в игру Стреляй на меткость с преимуществом в 2 очка.

в то время как

> Пользователь Вася Пупкин проиграл пари пользователю Таня Галина в игру Стреляй на меткость с *перевесом??* *недостатком?* в 2 очка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

И проиграть и выиграть можно с разницей (в) 2 очка.

Answer (score 0):

Если суть пари была "кто из двоих больше очков наберёт", то, например, "*отстав на 2 очка*". Менее убедительно "с отставанием в два очка" (так больше говорят о незаконченном состязании). Это не совсем пари, больше спор "кто лучше играет".

Если же вопрос стоял "спорим, что ты не выбьешь столько-то очков", то Вася проиграл "*недобрав 2 очка*" или "*с недобором 2 очков*". Такое пари и выигрывают не с преимуществом (перевесом), а с "запасом".

Answer (score 0):

Можно написать: проиграть с перевесом в 2 очка. Но если вы переводите сайт,почему бы не воспользоваться тем термином, которой указан на сайте?

Answer (score 0):

Дайте оригинальный текст.
А то тут игра в угадайку началась.
Вообще все варианты (с разницей, с недобором и проч.) возможны, но они сильно зависят от контекста, в данном случае - от смысла исходного текста, и я бы не рекомендовал что-то одно на все случаи жизни.

Вообще, если не по конкретному вопросу, у слова "преимущество" в русском языке нет всеобъемлющего антонима. 
Говорят обычно что-то типа "Проиграл, уступив два очка" или просто "уступил два очка". Не знаю, насколько жто подходит для вашего случая.

Как туда challenge (вызов?) попал - не очень представляю.

Кстати, вопросы по переводам, если Ваш английский позволяет, лучше задавать здесь
http://russian.stackexchange.com